# With Ruby/Rails5, How can I loop through the most recent 4 weeks and collect an aggregate sum?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

Given the table:

```
Log Table: id, user_id, points, created_at
```

Goal is to go 4 weeks back and per week obtain the cumulative points up to that point:

```
"05/29/2017", total_points (= the Big Bang to this date)
"06/5/2017", total_points (= the Big Bang to this date)
"06/12/2017", total_points (= the Big Bang to this date)
"06/19/2017", total_points (= the Big Bang to this date)
```

With Ruby/Rails5, How can I loop through the most recent 4 weeks and collect the point count?

Thanks

Comment: What database are you using

Comment: Postgres is the db I'm using :)

Comment: and on most recent weeks, does that include the current week?

Comment: yes please, the most recent week would be the current week whether that means 1 day or 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple ActiveRecord query in a loop

```
points = (1..4).map do |n|
   Log.where("created_at <= ?", n.weeks.ago).sum(:points)
end
```

`n.weeks.ago` will be transformed into a date object, thanks to ActiveSupport.

Eg:

`2.weeks.ago => 2017-06-07 16:45:33`

**EDIT:**

I just read in a comment that you want to consider **whole** weeks, (monday to sunday) and that the first week should be the current week.

Try with:

```
points = (0..3).map do |n|
   Log.where("created_at <= ?", n.weeks.ago.end_of_week).sum(:points)
end
```

Comment: this is great thank you... It returns 0 for weeks w no points